# Boost asio: io service is blocked during destruction step more some handler trouble

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

To manage tcp communication i'm using boost asio version 1.48 with x64 project setting on visual studio 10 with sdk 7.1 and windows 7.

I designed a class with inner members:

- asio IO Service.
- asio tcp ipv4 Socket.
- asio Strand.
- a list of received Messages.
- a pointer to a boost thread.

During debug runtime, process follow the next steps :

1. construct the object and inner attributs io service, socket, strand
   and a pointer to a thread.
2. create an async connection with the created socket
3. listen to message header with an async read.
4. create a thread which call io service run.
5. A header message is read, listen to message body called in a strand
   with async read.
6. stack the message and call treatement in IOservice via post function
   and a handler.
7. listen to message header with an async read.
8. repeat n time step 5 to 7.
9. cancel then close the socket.
10. stop and reset the io service.
11. destroy the object.

I have two major troubles:

=> The connection handler is never called but connection is done !
Handler function:=

```
void CManager::HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator it)
```

=> during destroying process program block in file boost\asio\detail\impl\win_iocp_io_service.ipp l358:

```
BOOL ok = ::GetQueuedCompletionStatus(iocp_.handle, &bytes_transferred,
        &completion_key, &overlapped, block ? gqcs_timeout : 0);
```

I don't understand why?

**Edit:**

My code:

Note that my worst trouble is program block during destruction of msgManager instance !

best Regards.

```
CManager::CManager(const char* _ipAdress, const char* _port):    
    m_MsgFactory(),
    m_IOService(),
    m_Socket(m_IOService),
    m_Strand(m_IOService),
    m_ReceivedMsgs(),
    m_pThread(nullptr)
{
    Start( _ipAdress, _port);
}

CManager::~CManager(void)
{
}

CManager::TThread* CManager::GetThread(void)
{
    return m_pThread;
}

void CManager::Start(const char* _ipAdress, const char* _port)
{
    CreateConnection( _ipAdress, _port);

    if(nullptr == m_pThread)
    {
        m_pThread = new TThread( boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,&m_IOService) );
    }
}

void CManager::Stop()
{
    CloseConnection();

    m_IOService.stop();
    m_IOService.reset();
}

void CManager::CreateConnection(const char* _ipAdress, const char* _port)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(m_IOService);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query( boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), std::string(_ipAdress), std::string(_port) );
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endPointIt = resolver.resolve(query);

    // Start an asynchronous connect operation.
    boost::asio::async_connect(m_Socket, endPointIt, boost::bind(&CManager::HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, endPointIt));

    //Previous handler is never called. Without next code, asio log in consol show a cancel message !
    Listen();
}

void CManager::HandleConnect(const boost::asio::placeholders::error& error, TResolver::iterator it)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        Listen();
    }
}

void CManager::CloseConnection()
{
    m_Socket.cancel();
    m_Socket.close();
}

void CManager::Listen(void)
{
        TMsgPtr pMsg(new TMsg());

        CMsgBase::TMsgBuffer headerBuffer;
        if(!pMsg->GetHeaderBuffer(headerBuffer))
        {            
            return;
        }

        boost::asio::async_read(m_Socket,
                                headerBuffer,
                                m_Strand.wrap( boost::bind(&CManager::HandleReadMsg, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, pMsg) ) );        
}

void CManager::HandleReadMsg(const boost::asio::placeholders::error& error, TMsgPtr _pMsgBase )
{
    if (!error && nullptr != _pMsgBase &&  true == _pMsgBase->HasBody() )
    {
        CMsgBase::TMsgBuffer       bodyBuffer;
        _pMsgBase->GetBodyBuffer( bodyBuffer );

        //Next treatment.
        boost::asio::async_read(m_Socket,
                                bodyBuffer,
                                m_Strand.wrap( boost::bind(&CManager::HandleMsg, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, _pMsgBase) ) );
    }
    else
    {
        Listen();
    }
}

void CManager::HandleMsg(const boost::asio::placeholders::error& error, TMsgPtr _pMsgBase )
{
    if (!error && nullptr != _pMsgBase)
    {
        m_ReceivedMsgs.push_back( _pMsgBase );

        //post will not call the function directly but postpone the call in io service.
        m_IOService.post( boost::bind(&CManager::TranslateMsg, this) );
    }

    //Still listen for next messages.
    Listen();
}

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        /*Some code*/

        boost::thread_group threadGroup;

        CManager msgManager( ipAddress, ipPort );
        threadGroup.add_thread( msgManager.GetThread() );

        /*Some code*/

        msgManager.Stop();
        threadGroup.join_all();

        /*Some code*/
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        /*Some code*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We don't understand why either.  Seeing the declaration of your handler isn't very useful, we need to see how you "call" it (how you are passing that handler to `async_connect()`).  Also, there are lots of things that can cause existing queued operations to block.  We will need to see more code to effectively help.

Comment: I add my code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a lifetime issue with objects that you have posted to the `io_service` being destructed while still pending in the `io_service` queue.

You should make sure you give all of your handlers that may be holding references to objects that you've created a chance to execute.  I notice that you bind your handlers to pointers of the `CManager`, this means that for safety's sake you should let all handlers posted bound to that `CManager` instance execute (either successfully or with an error) before that instance of `CManager` is destructed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, i want to listen to new message while the application is running. So, i always call listen function when a message deserialization end. If i understand your answer, if this handler isn't executed i can't destroy my object. Is there a better pattern to follow ? Best regards.

Comment: The `io_service::run` function will continue until there is no more work do to.  If you close your socket then all pending IO operations will be cancelled.  Once all the pending handlers have been executed, then the `io_service::run` function should return.  At that time it would likely be safe to destroy your objects.  Lifetime management with `boost::asio` can be complicated.